# Permission Denied when i try to create a file - Android8+ - App in System Mode

Tags: android, permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I'm developing an app that is installed in System Mode. He comes factory installed like Google Play, Facebook, Email... The app download a zip file by Download Manager like this way:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);     
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);      request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destination, filename + fileextention);
```

Destination is DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;

Then i do the file's unzip:

```
cr = context.getContentResolver();
        try {
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(sourceFile))));
            //zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));
            ZipEntry ze;
            int count;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                String fileName = ze.getName();

                fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("/") + 1);
                File file = new File(destinationFolder, file_name);

                File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
                Log.i("MainService", "Unzipping fileName: " + fileName);

                file_path = destinationFolder + "/" + fileName;

                if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
                if (ze.isDirectory()) continue;
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                } finally {
                    fout.close();
                }

                list_filenames.add(file_downloaded);

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d("MainService", "Error catch: " + ioe.getMessage());
            return list_filenames;
        } finally {
            if (zis != null)
                try {
                    zis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
        }
```

Here is the problem. I'm getting Permission Denied after first loop on While. I take the first file name inside the zip, then the app goes to Catch ( Log.d("MainService", "Error catch: " + ioe.getMessage())) with Permission Denied and the Unzip method stops.

I was thinking that when my app is installed in System Mode they don't need users permissions. By the way..That's my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking permission at run time?

Comment: I'm not, because the user cannot deny the permission. The app runs in background and does not have UI. Like i said, he comes factory installed and does customization after first boot. Dont need interact with user and is istalled in System mode.

Comment: Yes.My app has system-level access

Answer (score 0):

First. Ask permissions in runtime.
Second. You need to add some code. For the latest Android versions, this is not enough `Uri.parse(sourceFile)` 
This [article](https://medium.com/@ali.dev/open-a-file-in-another-app-with-android-fileprovider-for-android-7-42c9abb198c1) will help you

Comment: But my app cannot interact with user and is istalled in System mode. Even my app having system level access i need ask for permission?